# What is the difference between Zookeeper and the load balancer?

Tags: load-balancing, apache-zookeeper

What is the difference between Zookeeper and the load balancer ?

Answer (score 7):

ZooKeeper is used for High Availability, but not as a Load Balancer exactly.

High Availability means, you don't want to loose your single point of contact i.e. your master node. If one master goes down there should be some else who can take care and maintain the same state.

Load Balancer is used to balance your different kinds of loads like network and application services. If there is a high demand flows for the application, an application load balancer delegates the task to it's available instances. If there is huge calls at network layer, an network load balancer plays an role to handle the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have a little different opinion with ParShuram.

Zookeeper is healthy checking each service and only when they are healthy, it routes traffic to the server. It provides various functionality but at the end of the day it is a load balancer.

Below is definition of Zookeeper

Zookeeper is registry for large distributed systems. It is beneficial for tasks like master election, crash detection and managing meta data related to distributed systems. In simple terms, load balancer helps in distribution of workload across multiple servers

Comment: `but at the end of the day it is a load balancer`, i disagree with it, the reason you need load balancer is so that your server wont be overloaded for whatever reason. Imagine you have 3 servers to handle 30 requests, these 30 requests ideally would be spread across 3 servers so that every server handle 10 requests AT THE SAME TIME.

Zookeeper on the other hand ensures that there will always be 1 master server and if that master server gone down, another server from the pool will take over, which also means, the server is handling 30 requests AT THE SAME TIME